# Select an element with specific attribute

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a form:

```
<form method='somemethod' action='someaction' id='someid' populate='empty or non-empty'> 
  form elements
</form>
```

I wan to create a jQuery function that should alert 'populate' value whenever a form with populate attribute is loaded in webpage. Forget about populate value.

Means if form has populate attribute alert otherwise dont alert. How to achieve this??

Thanks

Comment: By "... a form with populate attribute is loaded in webpage ..." you mean loaded via ajax?

Comment: @Yoshi: May be form is not loaded via ajax but that webpage include a JS file with ready function...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ($('form[populate]').length) {
   alert('Attribute present');
}
```

Check the length property

Answer (score 1):

see jQuery's [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method.

```
$('form[populate]').live('click', function() {
    alert('Found it');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use **[jQuery.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)**  introduced in *jQuery v1.6*

`$('form').prop('populate')`

will return the value of populate, as it is mention [here](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

> **.prop( propertyName )** : propertyNameThe name of the property
>   to get.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form[populate]').each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        if ($this.attr('populate')) {
            alert( $this.attr('populate') );
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('form').each(function(el){
    if(typeof el.populate!='undefined')alert('whatever');
  })
});
```

There.

Answer (score 0):

You actually want to use data-populate since the HTML5 spec allows for it. "data-anything-here" is also valid.